# Modal bottom sheet not re-rendering itself when parent updates its own state

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

**Scenario and requirements:**

I want to load some strings from a Repository. In this example, we load them from a local Repository with **Future.delayed()**.

We have a button to show all names. These names **should be listed inside a showModalBottomSheet()**. If the names have not been loaded, the showModalBottomSheet() should show a circular progress indicator. If the names are loaded, the showModalBottomSheet() should show the names.

**The problem**

The showModalBottomSheet() code shows the circular progress indicator if time passed is less than 3 seconds, and it also shows the names if time passed is greater than 3 seconds. **BUT**, if we open the showModalBottomSheet() before 3 seconds have passed, **and leave it open**, the contents of the showModalBottomSheet() **should re-render automatically** because the names are loaded after 3 seconds, but **the circular progress indicator never goes away**, because the bottom sheet **never triggers a re-render**, even if the List has already been loaded from the Repository.

**Code**

I have the following **minimal reproducible example**. It compiles and runs correctly:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(title: 'Title', home: Home());
  }
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Scaffold(
      body: HomeBody(),
    );
  }
}

class HomeBody extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeBody({super.key});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _HomeBodyState();
}

class _HomeBodyState extends State<HomeBody> {
  final NamesRepository _namesRepository = NamesRepository();

  late List<String> _names;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _names = [];
    _namesRepository.loadNames().then((names) => setState(() {
          _names = names;
        }));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      child: const Text('Show all names'),
      onPressed: () => _onButtonClick(context),
    );
  }

  void _onButtonClick(BuildContext context) {
    showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        if (_names.isEmpty) {
          return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        } else {
          return Column(
            children: _names.map((name) => Text(name)).toList(),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}

class NamesRepository {
  Future<List<String>> loadNames() {
    return Future.delayed(
      const Duration(seconds: 3),
      () => ['John', 'Maria', 'Lewis', 'Danny'],
    );
  }
}
```

What should I do, so that the modal bottom sheet re-renders automatically when the List is loaded from the Repository? As you can see, I am calling setState() in the parent Widget, but the modal bottom sheet still does not re-render itself on state change. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
usually doing a setState() in Parent widget will not have effect in modelsheet because both use different context.
you try instead,
  void _onButtonClick(BuildContext context) {
    showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return ModelSheet();
      },
    );
  }

and have ModelSheet as StatefulWidget and do the init method here, it will work.

class _ModelSheetState extends State<ModelSheet> {
  final NamesRepository _namesRepository = NamesRepository();

  late List<String> _names;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _names = [];
    _namesRepository.loadNames().then((names) => setState(() {
          _names = names;
        }));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return if (_names.isEmpty) {
          return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        } else {
          return Column(
            children: _names.map((name) => Text(name)).toList(),
          );
        }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used `ChangeNotifierProvider` from [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) and used `ChangeNotifierProvider.value` in the **bottomsheet**.

Here's how the `HomeBody` looks:

> NOTE:
> It's important to make sure to use the **provider's builder *context***:
> `builder: (context, _) {}`

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class HomeBody extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeBody({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => HomeBodyNotifier(),
      builder: (context, _) {
        return ElevatedButton(
          child: const Text('Show all names'),
          onPressed: () => _onButtonClick(context),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  void _onButtonClick(BuildContext context) {
    showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      builder: (_) {
        return ChangeNotifierProvider<HomeBodyNotifier>.value(
          value: context.watch<HomeBodyNotifier>(),
          builder: (context, _) {
            final names = context.watch<HomeBodyNotifier>().names;

            if (names.isEmpty) {
              return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            } else {
              return Column(
                children: names.map((name) => Text(name)).toList(),
              );
            }
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class HomeBodyNotifier extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<String> names = [];

  HomeBodyNotifier() {
    loadNames();
  }

  void loadNames() {
    Future.delayed(
      const Duration(seconds: 3),
      () {
        names.addAll(['John', 'Maria', 'Lewis', 'Danny']);
        notifyListeners();
      },
    );
  }
}
```